# What is a Damn Dorothy Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Damn Dorothy Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

Damn Dorothy Words™,Not Damn Dorothy Words™
AIM,PUN
FLYBY,FLAG
GOURD,JOINT
MAN,BAD
PYX,SIX
RUSK,FUME
TEE,TOY
WORK,QUIT

Comment: three in a row? :/

Comment: I thought there is a 20 minute cooldown period network-wide for asking questions. Obviously I was wrong.

Comment: Solving the title will give you a hint: (4, 3)

Comment: Something related to **Dorothy Adams**? :-/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A Damn Dorothy Word™ is a word ...

> ... whose representation in Morse code uses only letters with the same number of signals. For example, AIM is `.- .. --` and the Morse codes for the letters A, I and M all have two signals. (Here, a signal is either a dot or a dash.) Conversely, the letters of Not Damn Dorothy Words™ have varying signal lengths in Morse code.

They are called Damn Dorothy Words™, because ...

> ... "Damn Dorothy!" could be rephrased to "Dash Dot!". (The OP hints at this in a comment and helpfully provides the letter emuneration.) This does not define the characteristics, but hints at Morse code.

Evidence section:

> ```
> AIM     ·- ·· --
> FLYBY   ··-· ·-·· -·-- -··· -·--
> GOURD   --· --- ··- ·-· -··
> MAN     -- ·- -·
> PYX     ·--· -·-- -··-
> RUSK    ·-· ··- ··· -·-
> TEE     - · ·
> WORK    ·-- --- ·-· -·-
>
> PUN     ·--· ··- -·
> FLAG    ··-· ·-·· ·- --·
> JOINT   ·--- --- ·· -· -
> BAD     -··· ·- -··
> SIX     ··· ·· -··-
> FUME    ··-· ··- -- ·
> TOY     - --- -·--
> QUIT    --·- ··- ·· -
> ```

Comment: Can you explain how (4,3) gives Dash Dot? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot: (4, 3) is only the enumeration of letters in the answer, as is seen in crossword puzzles. Dash! and Damn! are expletives and Dot is a name given to women called Dorothy, so "Damn Dorothy" becomes "Dash Dot". The OP says that there is a hint in the title and then provides the enumeration.